# Java Generics Class which can consume its own product generated by factory

Tags: java, generics

Sorry for the wired title but it boils down to the point ...

The Problem can be described like this:

I've got a `Worker<P>` class which can be configured to produce "some" Product. This `Worker` must be able to consume its own Product (and only its own product, this is the whole point of the exercise):

```
interface Worker<P> {
    public P produce();
    public void consume( P p );
}
```

**(cannot be changed)**

So far so easy but now the product itself can be configured:

```
interface ConfiguredProduct<T> {
    public T value();
}
```

**(cannot be changed)**

Now the workers are generated by a factory (which in real life is itself created using a config file)

```
static class Hatchery {

    public <X extends CharSequence, Y extends ConfiguredProduct<X>> Worker<Y> breed() {

        return new StringWorker(); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test.StringWorker to Test.Worker<Y>
    }
}
```

**(may be changed)**

**And I like to use it in a way like this:**

```
public static <perhapse some wired arguments> void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {

    Hatchery hatchery = new Hatchery(); // Cannot be parametrized here

    Worker<T> worker = hatchery.breed();

    ConfiguredProduct<wired arguments> product = worker.produce();

    worker.consume( product );
}
```

examples for the Workers may be:

```
static class StringWorker implements Worker<ConfiguredProduct<String>> {

    @Override
    public ConfiguredProduct<String> produce() {
        return () -> "Hello";
    }

    @Override
    public void consume( ConfiguredProduct<String> p ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello " + p.value() );
    }
}

static class StringBufferWorker implements Worker<ConfiguredProduct<StringBuffer>> {

    @Override
    public ConfiguredProduct<StringBuffer> produce() {
        return () -> new StringBuffer( "Hello" );
    }

    @Override
    public void consume( ConfiguredProduct<StringBuffer> p ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello " + p.value().toString() );
    }
}
```

Is this even possible without casting wildly? I tried every combination of generic arguments in any places I can think of but it did produce errors at one point or another.

EDIT: Added notes which parts cannot be changed. Added usage and notes to the `Hatchery`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Product and ConfiguredProduct? It's not clear to me if the latter is an extension interface of the former. Also, why do you define Y in your breed() method? It isn't used. Please filter out all unneeded stuff in your question because it confuses people.

Comment: Hi Timmos. X/Y was a typo and now is corrected. "Product" itself is not a class but merely the generic parameter `P` (read: something specific which may be produced). `ConfiguredProduct<T>` is such a thing. It's sometimes hard to come up with names/analogons to stuff which is something completely different in real code.

Comment: can you explain why you want to have generics in `breed`  method, as doesn;t matter on parameters, you will always return instance of `StringWorker`

Comment: @user902383: StringWorker is just a example in this case. It may return StringBufferWorker or some similar stuff. Like I wrote: "Now the workers are generated by a factory (which in real life is itself created using a config file)". Different factories return different Workers.

Comment: I think the main problem is the `Hatchery#breed` method. The information about the returned type does not "escape" this method in any way. You can basically define the return type *at the call site*, which *enforces* an unchecked cast (and thus, possible type errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will have different factories which returns different Workers, then you will have something like that:

```
static interface Hatchery {
    public <X extends CharSequence, Y extends ConfiguredProduct<X>> Worker<Y> breed();
}

static class WorkerHatchery implements Hatchery{
    public   Worker<ConfiguredProduct<String>> breed(){
        return new StringWorker();
    }
}
```

and then this code works without any problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Hatchery hatchery = new WorkerHatchery();
    Worker<ConfiguredProduct<String>> worker = hatchery.breed();
    ConfiguredProduct<String> product = worker.produce();
    worker.consume(product);
}
```

**Edit**
If you don't want to have any warnings, there is another alternative, you could move generics values on class, and you will have:

```
 interface Hatchery<X extends CharSequence, Y extends ConfiguredProduct<X>>{ 
       Worker<Y> breed();
    }

class WorkerHatchery implements Hatchery<String,ConfiguredProduct<String>> { 
        public Worker<ConfiguredProduct<String>> breed() {  
        return new  StringWorker();     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi user902383. Thanks for you answer. With the factories you are on the right track. This is indeed more like the actual code looks like. But there are two (or one and a half) problems with your code: The minor one is that `WorkerHatchery::breed` gives me a typesafety warning. But the major one is that in `main` I don't know that the product is a String product but only that it is a ConfiguredProduct (with some kind of CharSequence).

Comment: (actuall the real code would look like: `Hatchery h = HatcheryConfig.instance()` but I left this part out in the hopes to not making it overly complicated)

Comment: your major problem you can solve by changing keyword `String` to `CharSequence` in main method. and typesafe warning you can suppress by putting annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on breed method

Comment: If I make `Hatchery` generic, I can only use it as (in this case) Hatcher<?,?> in main.

Comment: With CharSequence you are right. This does finally work! Additionally in your code you could change `public Worker<ConfiguredProduct<String>> breed()` to `public StringWorker breed()`. All what's left is the `unchecked` warning. I think I have to live with that even if I don't like it ...

Comment: (meanwhile I found another solutions with their own drawbacks. parametrizing main with `<U extends CharSequence, T extends ConfiguredProduct<U>>` and using it for `Worker<T>` and `T product` works, too)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class Test {

    private interface Product<X> {
        public X getValue();
    }

    private static class StringProduct implements Product<String> {

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }

    private interface Worker<X> {
        public Product<X> produce();

        public void consume(Product<? extends X> p);
    }

    private static class StringWorker implements Worker<String> {

        @Override
        public StringProduct produce() {
            return new StringProduct();
        }

        @Override
        public void consume(Product<? extends String> p) {
            System.out.println(p.getValue());
        }
    }

    private interface WorkerFactory<T extends Worker<?>> {
        public T breed();
    }

    private static class StringWorkerFactory implements WorkerFactory<StringWorker> {

        @Override
        public StringWorker breed() {
            return new StringWorker();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkerFactory<StringWorker> factory = new StringWorkerFactory();
        Worker<String> worker = factory.breed();

        Product<String> product = worker.produce();

        worker.consume(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Timos. Thank you for your answer. But this changes to much of the problem. The factory cannot be parametrized because at this point the product is not known. (More precise: It's only known that it is of type `ConfiguredProduct<T>` and that T extends CharSequence)